# Boost.Test - How to check two vectors on intersection?

Tags: c++, boost, boost.test

I'm looking for the best way to check two vectors for intersections.

A nested loop like

```
for (auto const & first: first_vector)
  for (auto const & next: next_vector)
    if first == next
      return false;
```

could do the job but it does not look like a Boost.Test-ish way. Neither a look at [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) helps a lot as the only test case predefined is [BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/testing_tool_ref/assertion_boost_level_eq_collections.html)

## Update

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(paths,fixture_t)
{
  for(int i=0,j=vids.size(); i!=j; i++)
  {
    for(int p=0,q=vids.size(); p!=q; p++)
    {
      if (i == p)
      {
        continue;
      }
      if (i < p)
      {
        BOOST_TEST_CONTEXT("Equal match at positions " << i << " and " << p)

        BOOST_TEST(vids[i] != vids[p]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Comment: Performance depends a lot on the size of both vectors. If `std::set_intersection` isn't good enough, you'll need to explain why. Hint: if both vectors are large, you can make a BST out of one of them, which will speed things up significantly.

Comment: `std::set_intersection` is fine but how to get the corresponding answer out of `Boost.Test` in a manner like `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS` does (values and exact position)?

Comment: How large is each vector?

Comment: some hundreds or thousands entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In unit tests you usually don't care about performance of validating code as long as it is reasonable.

I would just write a template function `sets_intersect` taking two vectors, inserting one of them into `std::hash_set` and traversing the second vector until the first match. Or just sorting them both and checking with `std::set_intersection`.

The final syntax will be something like `BOOST_CHECK(sets_intersect(vec1, vec2))`, which looks human friendly enough.